# Convert INT com 0x prefix to String with Python

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, integer, prefix

How?

```
x = 0x2629c46c0700222a18194b5ede91752fab626631
z = str(x)
print(z)
```

Result,

```
results = 217873090612289198846821204309205719268513179185
```

I want this ->  `'0x2629c46c0700222a18194b5ede91752fab626631'`

Comment: Try: `f'0x{x:x}'`

Comment: This question is almost certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x = 0x2629c46c0700222a18194b5ede91752fab626631
print(f'0x{x:0x}')
```